# Abbauen und nachlassen - der Unterschied

Tags: word-choice, synonym

Der Duden sagt:

> **abbauen:** 1. allmählich an Stärke, Intensität verlieren; weniger, schwächer werden
>
> **nachlassen:** 8.  in der Leistung nachlassen, an Kraft, Konzentration verlieren

Ist also nachlassen von engerer Bedeutung als abbauen?

Comment: Was genau meinst Du mit "engerer Bedeutung"? Du zitierst die _achte_ Bedeutung von "nachlassen"; wie soll das dann engere (spezialisiertere?) Bedeutung haben als "abbauen", wo der Duden nur vier Erklärungen anbietet?

Comment: Ich meinte: kann abbauen in der zitierten Bedeutung irgendetwas beliebig betreffen und nachlassen nur die Leistungen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Grundbedeutungen überschneiden sich; in dieser Schnittmenge liegt der m.E. wesentliche Unterschied im Bezug:

- Abbauen bezieht sich auf ein **Ganzes**, z.B. 'Großvater baut immer schneller ab.'
- Nachlassen kann man zwar umgangssprachlich gleich verwenden, im allgemeinen wird man es aber auf bestimmte **Teilleistungen** beziehen: 'Seine Sehkraft lässt immer schneller nach.'

Answer (score 2):

Allgemein finde ich weder "nachlassen" noch "abbauen" enger. "abbauen" kann Verschiedenes betreffen, aber das gilt auch für "nachlassen". Je nach Aussage / Kontext würde ich aber "nachlassen" und "abbauen" nicht als gleichwertig betrachten.

Dass "nachlassen" sich nicht nur auf Leistung bezieht, siehst Du auch schon an Deinem Beispiel aus dem Duden.

> Der Sturm lässt nach.
>
> Der Druck lässt nach.

In diesen Beispielen würde ich nicht "abbauen" verwenden.

> Der Schüler lässt nach (bringt schlechtere Leistungen in der Schule).
>
> Der Sprinter lässt nach (wird langsamer).

Hier geht auch "abbauen".

> Der Patient baut (gesundheitlich) ab.

Hier würde ich "nachlassen" nicht verwenden, auch wenn es nicht völlig falsch klingt.

Für mein Wortgefühl ist "abbauen" eher aktiv (man baut etwas ab), während "nachlassen" eher passiv ist (etwas wird schwächer, ohne dass man etwas dafür tut).

Comment: Mein Gefühl betreffend Aktivität ist genau andersherum …

Answer (score 1):

Abbauen geschieht durch eine Kraft von außen, Nachlassen durch eine Kraft von Innen. Nachlassen hat eine selbständige/automatische Komponente, Abbauen nicht.

Der Alkoholpegel **wurde** binnen 3h vom Körper **abgebaut**. (Aktiv durch Enzyme)

Meine Liebe zu ihr **ließ** immer stärker **nach**. (von selbst)

Comment: Welche Kraft von außen sorgt dafür, dass man mental *abbaut*, oder die Sehstärke *abbaut*?

Comment: Keine, die Sehstärke läßt nach. Abbauende Sehstärke ist inhaltlich falsches Deutsch.

Comment: BTW, man könnte natürlich sagen: die Sehstärke *wird* abgebaut, dann müsste aber folgen bzw. irgendwo erklärt werden: *wodurch*?

Comment: Die Antwort bezieht sich nicht auf die intransitive Bedeutung von *abbauen*, um die es in der Frage geht.